# Export multiple matching pattern

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to extract `AOB1` or `AOB2` or `AOB3` from the string below.

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,2,3),
  string = c("acv-32-AOB1", "osa-122-AOB2","cds-543-rr-AOB3")
)

> df
  id          string
1  1     acv-32-AOB1
2  2    osa-122-AOB2
3  3 cds-543-rr-AOB3
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `trimws` from `base R`

```
trimws(df$string, whitespace =".*-")
[1] "AOB1" "AOB2" "AOB3"
```

---

Or use `sub` from `base R`

```
sub(".*-", "", df$string)
[1] "AOB1" "AOB2" "AOB3"
```

---

Or if we need to do extract the 'AOB' followed by digits

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(df$string, "AOB\\d+")
[1] "AOB1" "AOB2" "AOB3"
```

Comment: does the `trims` look at the end of the string? Would this work if `AOB1` is the middle?

Comment: yes I immediately used your last solution and it worked well. thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions for this:

1. `.*` Match anything
2. `(AOB[1-3])` then match AOB followed by a 1, 2 or 3
3. `\\1` replace the entire string with the matched AOB1-3 slot

```
gsub(".*(AOB[1-3])", "\\1", df$string)
```

Comment: thanks for your input. really appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I made some modification so that your desired pattern could be everywhere and you could use the following solution to extract it:

```
df$res <- gsub("(.*)?([A-Z]{3}\\d)(.*)?", "\\2", df$string, perl = TRUE)
df

  id          string  res
1  1     acv-32-AOB1 AOB1
2  2    osa-122-AOB2 AOB2
3  3 cds-543-rr-AOB3 AOB3
```

Comment: Thanks bro, I try to improve :)

Comment: thanks for your input and time. really appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Here is one more dear friends:

```
m <- gregexpr("[a-zA-Z]{3}\\d{1}", df$string)

unlist(regmatches(df$string, m))
```

```
> unlist(regmatches(df$string, m))
[1] "AOB1" "AOB2" "AOB3"
```